Checking return value of multiple functions in main function, if all functions return False, print ("not involved")
I want to write a code with many functions in it if the output of all functions in the code is False, the code will return "not involved".
Something  like the below code:
def func1():
     if func1() and func2() and func3() ==False:
         print("not involved")


if not func1() and not func2() ……?

As written, your code will recurse which you almost certainly don't want

You could utilise the built-in all() function like this:
def func1():
    return False

def func2():
    return True

def func3():
    return False

if all(not f() for f in (func1, func2, func3)):
    print("Not involved")

This will not produce any output. Change func2 to return False and the output will be:
Not involved

